# include and import azure rm module for powershell script in azure function

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, azure-rm

I am trying to establish scheduled run of powershell script using azure function.
My problem is that powershell script contains azureRM cmdlts and when i am trying to run the script it gives me an error:
"The specified module 'AzureRM' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory."

According to documentation azure modules are natively available, just need to make sure those two files contain following:

```
**host.json**
{
    “version”: “2.0”,
    “managedDependency”: {
       “Enabled”: “true”
    }
}

**Requirements.psd1**
@{
    Az = ‘1.*’
}
```

To solve the problem i used Kudu tool and made sure i have those values in above files. In the script i added a line

```
Import-Module -Name AzureRM
```

Unfortunately no success so far - still the same error.
Does anyone know how to import this module and make the script work in azure functions?
Will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Functions v2.0 do not support **AzureRM** modules, use **Az** instead.

If you invoke `Enable-AzureRmAlias` from profile.ps1, you can use the AzureRM cmdlet aliases provided by **Az**. When you create a new PowerShell app, your auto-generated profile.ps1 will normally contain something like this:

```
# Authenticate with Azure PowerShell using MSI.
# Remove this if you are not planning on using MSI or Azure PowerShell.
if ($env:MSI_SECRET -and (Get-Module -ListAvailable Az.Accounts)) {
    Connect-AzAccount -Identity
}

# Uncomment the next line to enable legacy AzureRm alias in Azure PowerShell.
# Enable-AzureRmAlias
```

Also, consider replacing `Az = ‘1.*’` with Az = `‘2.*’` in your requirements.psd1.

Comment: You could go for '3.*' now!  
It'll be 4.* pretty soon